# what is the best way to use MaterialPageRoute in list view

Tags: flutter

I have this ListView and I want to add a MaterialPageRoute. How can I do it that it opens a diverent page when I click on anoter item from the ListView.

(I dont want to want to send selected item data to next screen)

Example:
I click on ExamplePage it shod Navigate to ExamplePage() when I click on TestPage it shod Navigate to TestPage()

```
Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(    
          itemCount: categories.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return ExamplePage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                height: 150,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        child: Image.asset(
                            'images/${categories[index].imgName}.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            Text(
                              categories[index].name,
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                            )
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
```